# Reduce unwanted noise of image from phone by open-cv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a trouble with my image was taken by phone. I can't reduce unwanted noise of my photo

I have tried to increase contrast and also brightness but it's not effective

```py
 img = cv2.imread(image_path, 0)

    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11,
                                   2)  # Convert Image To Binary

    plt.imshow(img)
```

This is my original photo

[image: original]

This is my photo after processing

[image: result]

This is my expected photo

[image: expected]

Answer (score 0):

You have used the right thresholding method to produce the binary image from the original image, whereas it needs some optimization to get the best result:

```
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('aa.jpg', 0)
blur = cv.medianBlur(img,11)
# blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img,(11,11),0)
thresh = cv.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 4)

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img)
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(thresh)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand if you need also to filter off the pen marks, because in that case you need something more complex.
Anyway in your code the mistake is just in

```
plt.imshow(img)
```

you just plot your original image and not the filtered one...try this

```
plt.imshow(blur)
```

or this

`plt.imshow(thresh)`

and check the results